# How to configure Nginx to redirect URI without port?

Tags: google-oauth, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server running a WebApp with NGINX.
In Nginx I have configured the following under sites-available:

config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example www.example.de;

}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
        root /var/www/example.de/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.de www.example.de;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/_ssl_certificate.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/_private_key.key;

location / {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
}

location /auth/google/ {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4567/auth/google/;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}

}
```

Unfortunately I got the following error (nginx error log):
[error] 5875#5875: *3 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 12.123.12.0, server: example.de, request: "GET /auth/google/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:4567/auth/google/", host: "example.de"

I tried several proxy_passes and rewrite and redirect rules in NGINX config, but always failing..

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but my SSL certificates use the following protocols:
TLS 1.3 Yes
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 No
TLS 1.0 No
SSL 3 No
SSL 2 No

Comment: You're trying to make upstream connections with both HTTP and HTTPS on the same address and port, which doesn't work; those protocols are different. (The "wrong version" error here is actually an HTTP response not _any_ version of TLS/HTTPS.) If the upstream (webapp) actually supports both it must use -- and you must specify -- different ports. If it only supports HTTP, don't use HTTPS. And even if it does support HTTPS, using proxy_ssl_server_name on is ineffective when you specify the upstream host by address (127.0.0.1) -- SNI can _only_ transmit a name, not an address.

Comment: PS: this is proxying, or forwarding, pr relaying, but not redirection. Redirection in HTTP[S] is a specific thing and quite different.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the explanation on this. I tried to search for different solutions on proxying with Nginx and http but I still don't get the problem. 
I am using ssl certificates (see first lines in server section) and then im trying to proxy pass to https://localhost on specific port (where webapp runs). I can not figuring out where the "break" is.. for me it seems like it is an HTTPS connection..

Comment: As I said the problem is you are trying to do two different protocols, HTTP and HTTPS, FROM nginx TO 127.0.0.1:4567 and that is impossible. You are correctly using HTTPS with your cert-and-key on connections FROM other people/systems TO nginx on port 443, while also using HTTP to nginx on port 80; that is the 'downstream' side and is fine.